# Convert XML file to a table in the database, including column names

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have the following xml file

```
<Questions>
  <QuestionId=1>
  Which is a reserved word in the Java programming language?
    <Option1>
      method
    </Option1>
    <Option2>
      native
    </Option2>
    <Option3>
      subclass
    </Option3>
    <Option4>
      reference
    </Option4>
    <Answer>
    reference
    </Answer>
  </Question>
</Questions>
```

I need to create a table in the database where the value of Question becomes the column name and the Answers come in the row using C# and ASP.NET

Any help would be appreciated.

This is the format expected.

```
|A_ID||Which is a reserved word in the Java programming language?||Q2  |
________________________________________________________________________
|01  ||Reference                                                 ||A2  |
```

Comment: What do you mean with "create a table"? A UI Element? A database table?
What did you try to solve your problem?

Comment: A database table. So far I'm looking at the options.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you need 2 tables. 1 for the questions, and 1 for the answers. For simplicity I'm thinking of:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }

    //relations
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public bool Correct { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

    //relations
    public Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

Then with entityframework you can create migrations and your context and create your questions etc.

Makes any sense?

if your new to entity framework: check out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db